# When did COVID-19 hit the international news?

Tags: disease, television

I have been having a discussion about when COVID-19 first hit the international news.  I think it was around Christmas 2019, up to a couple of days after new year.  This is based on my recollection of telling zombie apocalypse jokes to the people I was with then. Others hold that it was not in international news until much later, though there is no agreement as to when that is.

I was not somewhere with over the air TV, so I would have heard the news on a streaming news service, one of [Al Jazeera](https://www.aljazeera.com/live), [CNN](https://go.cnn.com/) or [NPR](https://www.npr.org/programs/morning-edition/).  I have tried to find mention on their archived sites at the [Wayback machine](https://archive.org/) but failed to find any mention.

When was the first mention of the COVID-19 pandemic made in major international TV news?

Comment: This could well be difficult to pin down exactly because in the early stages it wasn't referred to as COVID-19 (or even Coronavirus).

Comment: [WHO timeline](https://www.who.int/news/item/27-04-2020-who-timeline---covid-19)  Or [Devex](https://www.devex.com/news/covid-19-a-timeline-of-the-coronavirus-outbreak-96396) "On Dec. 31, 2019, Chinese authorities alerted the World Health Organization of pneumonia cases in Wuhan City, Hubei province, China, with an unknown cause. What started as a mystery disease was first referred to as 2019-nCoV and then named COVID-19."  [NYtimes](https://www.nytimes.com/article/coronavirus-timeline.html).  If those don't answer, help us to understand what you're looking for?

Comment: I am asking when there was a report of the disease in the international news.  If for example there was a news report of the Chinese authorities alerted the WHO that would be an answer.  It would of course not require the pathogen to be specified, just that there was a disease worth reporting. The NYT is paywalled.

Comment: Does something here answer your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_COVID-19_pandemic_in_2019#First_international_alert

Comment: @NeMo Yes, I think it does.  I guess I really should have gone to wikipedia rather than trying on archive.org.

Comment: No problem. Wikipedia is so big these days that the article you need is sometimes quite hard to find. And not always accurate, though it tends to be quite good for this kind of thing.

Comment: The first mention in Germany's 20:00 evening news (which is as visible as you can get in Germany) was on January 20th, i.e. three days before Wuhan went into lockdown. There were earlier videos before then (around January 10th), but not in the main program. Web portals already had some articles on Dec. 31st.

Comment: The first reports I remember (late December/early January) were based on the situation described here: [Li Wenliang - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Wenliang)

Comment: @MCW: I thought 2019-nCoV ("novel Corona virus discovered in 2019") was the provisional designation of the virus before it was designated SARS-CoV-2, not the designation of the disease? In fact, I have an antigen test in my hand right now which is labeled "2019-nCoV antigen test" – I guess the manufacturer never bothered to redesign the imprint on the plastic casing.

Answer (score 0):

The news broke in early January 2020. You might want to consider [the BBC first top-news](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-50984025) dedicated to the pandemic as the starting point for the international news coverage. Early minor news exist in international newspapers [during early January](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/01/06/health/china-pneumonia-intl-hnk/index.html). News from Wuhan are available as early as December 2019 but they don't talk about covid-19 yet nor a pandemic. The pandemic is said to have started on [12th December 2019](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7095418/).

Comment: I may be being stupid, but it looks to me like the bbc news you link does not go back further than 1 year.

Comment: The link you give is from **15/12/2021**, not 2019.

Comment: Note also that BBC archives are unreliable - they are doctoring them "for PC reasons", but if they modify them at all, they cannot be trusted anymore, ever.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by replublished articles dates from the BBC. I've corrected the url. They republish articles many times so Google's algorithms think it's new content, to rank better.

Comment: @sds whatever the BBC may be doing (link?) that's not how sources work. The Bible has had a fair amount of tinkering but it's still a valuable historical source.

Comment: @NeMo: https://www.express.co.uk/showbiz/tv-radio/1554179/BBC-slammed-woke-cuts-editing-classic-shows-racial-slurs

Comment: @NeMo: The reliability of an Orwellian newspaper archive is dubious at best.

Comment: Now I know you're talking rubbish. This is about the BBC making changes to its *fictional* output, not revising old news articles!

Comment: @sds - I'm not seeing anything in that article that claims they are doing the kind of things that would *change* a reported date in one of their articles. You might find editing or "bleeping" out of older content that is considered objectionable later to be reprehensible, and that's your right, but its not really relevant here.

Comment: @T.E.D.: if they are making _any_ modifications of the archives, they cannot be trusted not to make other modifications. Basically, their archives cannot be relied upon any more than [Краткий курс](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Communist_Party_of_the_Soviet_Union_(Bolsheviks))

Comment: The BBC does not revise old articles, but they do revise the date of publication of its "posting" in the website. This is fairly common practice, by the way. If you use google tools > custom date range, you will find BBC coronavirus articles from 2018, before the pandemic even started, and 2018 articles posted as 2022 too.

Comment: @sds - I disagree. The motivation for doing it has nothing to do with this case, and neither does the action performed. If you cannot supply instances of them *changing* rather than simply editing out or removing content, its simply irrelevant soapboxing here.

Comment: @sds Agreeing with TED that your example looks less relevant than needed here. Compare eg http://web.archive.org/web/20181118111507/https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-46046067 to https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-46046067 and argue that this 'change'/'update' wasn't made transparent enough? By far. And yes, this is common practice for many online publications, undermining trust by being (almost) openly, but certainly positively unreliable. (No comment by me on either version of the content of that article). The practice on display must be stopped. Immediately.

Comment: Could you clarify the language "is said to have started": like 'eliminate passive voice', who said/says what, especially in light of 1. the Q about 'news headlines' 2. the established fact that the virus was well in global circulation _way_ earlier than December '19 (even symptoms for presumed index case started Dec 1)! 3. There was _no_  'pandemic' at all — until WHO declared it as such, as that is _a decision about names & definitions_.

Comment: @T.E.D. https://www.nationalreview.com/2022/01/the-bbc-quietly-censors-its-own-archives/  this may or may not be relevant to the specific article referred to in the answer, but it does cast a shadow of suspicion on BBC. Alas. At any rate, I don't think these comments are the right forum to discuss the issue.

Comment: @sds Here, we have [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=history.stackexchange.com) & also [meta]? I'd much appreciate some more refined meta-discussion on cavbeats like 'how reliable are srcs X,Y;Z'. [''The BBC' may be having some issues… but hey, we're on the internet… ;)]

Comment: @LаngLаngС: [as you wish](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4329/1979)